# How to use if in a filtered row in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

My table looks like this

```
Table: Money holder

SerialNo    Name 
123          A
456          A
789          B
```

```
Table: Collected by

SerialNo    Name
123          C
123          A
123          C
789          D
789          A
```

I need to see if there is any SerialNo with the same person in both the tables. What I tried to do was

```
CALCULATE( FIRSTNONBLANK('Collectedby'[Name], 1), FILTER(ALL('Collectedby'), Collectedby[SerialNo] = Moneyholder[serialno]))
```

And then I used `if` to see if the Name both are matching. But the issue here is that it looks for first value only and for Serial Number 123 it would be 'C'. But I used one more filter saying Moneyholder[name] = collectedby[name] then I would get blank for all other results.

How can I fixed this?

```
Desired Result: Table Money holder

SerialNo    Name     Collectedby
123          A           A
456          A           
789          B           D
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your expected results. How do you arrive at your result for 789|B? Your Collectedby table has only 789|D and 789|A.

Comment: @JosWoolley The 789|B is already in the original Money holder table. The CollectedBy is the new column where the result is derived.

Comment: Yes but I don't understand how your arrive at that result of D. There is no corresponding entry of 789|B in the Collected by table.